# Converting empty rows to commas in excel

Tags: excel

I have a text file like this.

```
Name

Address

Road

Name

Address

Road
```

I want to convert this to

```
Name,Address,Road
Name,Address,Road
```

I don't know how to do this in excel. Can anyone help? I have tried searching Google with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how automated you need it to be but this works:

1. Open the text file in excel so the fields show up in column A, each in it's own cell.
2. Number column B starting with 1, increment by 1 for each row(1-n where n is number of rows)
3. In column C insert a formula "=MOD(B1, 3)", this will give you the remainder of column B and 3
4. In column D, insert a formula, starting at the third row and going to the end of the rows:
              "=IF(C3=0,CONCATENATE(A1,",",A2,",",A3), "")", this will get you the comma separated rows you are looking for, but only in every third row, the rows in between will be blank.
5. Copy and paste column D into a new worksheet, delete the blank rows, either in excel or in the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

With the first `Name` in A2 (C1 blank), in B2:

```
=MOD(ROW(),3)
```

in C2:

```
=IF(B2=2,A2,C1&","&A2)
```

both copied down to suit. Then select, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top, Filter to select and delete `0` and `2` in ColumnB, then remove filter and delete ColumnB.

In effect very similar to @user2348184's approach, though perhaps a little simpler.

NB If the first `Address` is in A4, filter and delete blank rows (except Row1) first.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: `copied down to suit. Then select, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top` :/ Can you please elaborate?